# Prevent the uninstallation of Chrome's extensions on Kiwi Browser

Tags: browser

So I am on Kiwi Browser which allows me to use Chrome's extensions on Android. This is great and all, but I want to prevent the extension from being installed. I am doing this because of self-control and not to waste my time on different websites.

Is it possible I can make the extension uninstallable?